# How to get server interceptor/callback in case of keepalive failure?

Tags: node.js, grpc, keep-alive, grpc-node

I have a GRPC server in nodejs that manages client connections with proper keepalive options.

When I disconnect a cable, the server correctly detects that the client is no more reachable, as seen in the following logs:

```
E0129 17:05:32.252261922    5591 chttp2_transport.cc:2838]   ipv4:127.0.0.1:47520: Keepalive watchdog fired. Closing transport.
I0129 17:05:32.252320289    5591 connectivity_state.cc:147]  SET: 0x47dd758 server_transport: READY --> SHUTDOWN [close_transport]
```

I can't find a way to get this information through an event/callback/interceptor.

Does something exist for this?

Otherwise what is the use of this keepalive on server side if the high level code cannot detect it?

### Update

Despite the sad true reality of the answer,

### I found a workaround

by using a client side streaming and setting the keepalive options on server side. In this case, when connection issue happens, keepalive detects it and the streaming call triggers an 'end' event on the call.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The gRPC libraries are written so that the server-side application code deals with requests, not connections. They do not surface any events indicating that a connection has been established or lost.

The keepalive options only affect the client, and their main purpose is to stop servers and proxies from killing connections during periods of inactivity by sending HTTP/2 pings on those connections. Even with those options set, connections may still be dropped and recreated for whatever reason.